# Change Excel general to date format (office 365 or 2016)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

My spreadsheet shows Access Date in this format:
2020-04-16T17:08:28
This is clearly a date/time stamp. I need it to be displayed as mmmm/dd/yyyy

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To display in the format you mentioned, you can use this:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"mmmm/dd/yyyy")
```

More generally, to have any other function behave as if this is a date, just use the SUBSTITUTE part. You can then call YEAR, MONTH, DAY etc on the results of SUBSTITUTE.

[image]